# IDEA plugin: How to open the git windows and focus on special commit by commit id?

Tags: git, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I am developing a plugin to work with Git. I want to open the Git windows and focus on a special commit by the commit id.

I found I can open the Git window with this code:

```
ProjectLevelVcsManager.getInstance(project).showConsole();
```

But I have no idea how to focus on a special commit.

Comment: What constitutes a "special" branch? Or do you just mean the user should be able to input the name of some branch and commit ID? Then why both, though? A commit is already on a branch and cannot be on any other. Probably [edit] to explain in more detail what you mean.

Comment: (Please don't respond in comments; then we have to post another comment to tell you to delete the comment and repeat the request to edit the question instead.)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solve the problem,Here is the code :

```
String commitId = "123456"; //suppose it is commit id
VcsLogContentUtil.runInMainLog(project,(logUi) -> jumpToRevisionUnderProgress(project,logUi,commitId));


private void jumpToRevisionUnderProgress(Project project,VcsLogUiEx logUi,String commitId){
    //some null check
    //....
    Future<Boolean> future = VcsLogNavigationUtil.jumpToHash(logUi, commitId, false, true);
    if (!future.isDone()) {
      ProgressManager.getInstance().run(new Task.Backgroundable(project,
"my title", false,PerformInBackgroundOption.ALWAYS_BACKGROUND) {
        @Override
        public void run(@NotNull ProgressIndicator indicator) {
          try {
            future.get();
          }
          catch (CancellationException | InterruptedException ignored) {
          }
          catch (ExecutionException e) {
            LOG.error(e);
          }
        }
      });
    }
 }
```

Also see [IDEA Community](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/15647924711186-How-to-open-the-git-windows-and-focuse-on-special-brance-and-commit-)